# MYSQL get count of assignments in a course and count of how many a user has completed

Tags: mysql, sql

```
course
   id | name | description 

course_assignments
   id |course_id | description|...

user_assignments
   id| c_assignment_id | u_date
```

What I want to return is course id, COUNT(of course assignments), COUNT(users course assignments)

Currently I'm lazily using multiple sub queries and then joining the results onto the course_id.

```
 SELECT c.id, a.total, u.submitted
 FROM course
 JOIN(SELECT course_id, COUNT(*) as total FROM course_assignments 
 GROUP_BY course_id) as a ON a.course_id=c.id

JOIN (SELECT c_assignment_id, COUNT(*) as complete 
FROM course_assignments GROUP_BY c_assignment_id) as u ON    
a.id=u.c_assignment_id
```

What's the smarter way to do this?

Comment: Your method is quite reasonable and under many circumstances, the best approach.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff -  really. well how about that.....